# Leaflet polygons not showing when using html2canvas / Leaflet Save Map to PNG

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, html2canvas

I am trying to get an image in PNG from a map in leaflet, for it, I started using Leaflet-Save-Map-To-PNG, and it works well, but I have a problem. I'm representing polygons with a GeoJSON and when I obtain a map from it, I only obtain the tiles and markers, but not the polygons.

I have investigated several sites and one of the solutions to similar problems was to define a variable that forced Leaflet not to use SVG and using Canvas instead (L_PREFER_CANVAS = true;) but this made no difference in the result.

Here's my code:

```js
  html2canvas(jQuery('#mapdiv'), {
    useCORS: true,
    proxy: 'proxy.php',
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var img = canvas.toDataURL();
      dataURL = img.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
      $.post("save.php", {
        savedMap: dataURL
      }, function(data) {
        alert('Image Saved to : ' + data);
      });
    }
  });
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you post a full jsfiddle of your problem?

Comment: Hello @snkashis, we finally solve that issue in the project changing some of the technologies we were using. Thank you anyway for answering! :)

Comment: Could you outline how you solved this? Thanks.

Comment: @PeterBailey hi, we finally ended up using CesiumJS. There, with html2canvas, we could do it without problems.